# Can't install Webpack with node 12.0.0-pre and npm 6.6.0 OSX

Tags: webpack, node-gyp, fsevents

So I run the command `npm install -D webpack`

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v68-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@12.0.0-pre (node-v68 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 

...

../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:356:58: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
  return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:356:60: error: expected expression
  return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                                           ^
../fsevents.cc:43:32: error: no template named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
    static void Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports);
                           ~~~~^

...

../fsevents.cc:76:16: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
               ^
../fsevents.cc:76:31: error: no member named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                          ~~~~^
../fsevents.cc:76:48: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~^
../fsevents.cc:76:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'exports'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                                 ^
../fsevents.cc:76:58: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                                         ^
                                                         ;
22 warnings and 9 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
```

This wasn't happening the other day so I am not sure what caused it. I tried `npm cache clean -f` etc but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 7):

Had this problem myself today, solved it by removing `package.lock.json` and `node_modules`, then running `npm install` again.